# Typescript record error when using pointer like tree

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that goes through nodes and places them in a tree:

This is the interface type

```
interface IDataObj { 
    children: IDataObj[],
    frontmatter : { type: string, title: string, path: string},
    name: string,
    relativeDirectory: string,
  }
```

in which  have my pointer and tree:

```
let tree: Record<string, IDataObj> = {};
```

and within my `createNode` function:

```
let ptr: Record<string, IDataObj> = tree;
```

At a certain point within `createNode` have a simple algorithm that decided where to place a node and change the pointer of the tree:

```
        ptr[path[i]] = ptr[path[i]] || node;
        ptr[path[i]].children = ptr[path[i]].children || {};
        ptr = ptr[path[i]].children; // < this is giving me errors, ptr =
```

The last line where ptr now points to the chil

```
Type 'IDataObj[]' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, IDataObj>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'IDataObj[]'.
```

I'm unaware of how to solve this issue. It seems that fact that I'm using the ability of how loosely typed js is that I arrive at this issue.

Comment: Well, an array and and object with string keys are different. Use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a closer look at the types you have defined. You are saying I want to assign `children` a variable whose type is an `array`, to something whose type is essentially an `object`.